# Testing ServiceStack with Fiddler

Tags: fiddler, servicestack

I have built a service with ServiceStack (customer example) as per this link:   https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dg3mcfb_213gsvvmmfk

When I consume it the following way, it works well:

```
JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost/RestIntro");

Customer c = new Customer();
c.Name = "myname";
c.Age = 24;
c.Email = "myemail";

var res = client.Post<Customer>("/customers", c);
```

and it inserts the customer into the database.

But when I test it with Fiddler (`POST` request), it gives a 201 status message (created) but the database fields remain null, as shown in the following figure:

[image: Post request using fiddler]
[image: database status]

What could possibly be my issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the request header:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 44
Content-Type: application/json
```